# Expanding Disk partition in Fedora Linux

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fedora

[image: Current state of disk]

I was experimenting with dual booting and then finished. Now I want to take back the space that was used by the other OS. After deleting the other partition, I tried to expand the root partition to the now free space, but nothing will give me the option to do so. What can I do to reclaim the space?

There is 439 GB of free space, then 649 MB used by the boot EFI, then 1.1 GB used by boot, then the 560 GB File system Root partition I wish to expand.

I'm using Fedora 38 Linux and a 1Tb nvme.

I've tried using the GUI tools initially installed and then the G parted tool, neither of which would even give me the option to expand the root partition.

Comment: If you boot off a live ISO, you should be able to. https://gist.github.com/181192/cf7eb42a25538ccdb8d0bb7dd57cf236